# Determining a bootstrap CSS conflict

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */


body {background: #ccd3d7;}

div[class*='stack'] {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    margin: 40px;
}

div[class*='stack'], div[class*='stack']:before, div[class*='stack']:after {
    border: 6px solid #fff;
    height: 200px; width: 200px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    -moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}

div[class*='stack']:before, div[class*='stack']:after {
    background: #768590;
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
}

div[class*='stack']:before {
    background: #eff4de;
}

/*stack TWO*/
.stacktwo:before {
    top: 0px;
    left: -10px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-5deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-5deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-5deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-5deg);
    transform: rotate(-5deg);
}

.stacktwo:after {
    top: 5px; left: 0px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(4deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(4deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(4deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(4deg);
    transform: rotate(4deg);
}

/*stack THREE*/
.stackthree:before {
    top: 5px;
    left: -15px;
    z-index: -1;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-10deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-10deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-10deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-10deg);
    transform: rotate(-10deg);
}

.stackthree:after {
    top: -2px;
    left: -10px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-5deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-5deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-5deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-5deg);
    transform: rotate(-5deg);
}
```

[Here](http://designshack.net/articles/css/use-pseudo-elements-to-create-an-image-stack-illusion/) is some great code on this site to "stack" photos.  When using it with bootstrap.css it does not work properly.  How can I find the conflict?

The image loses it's border with bootstrap.css If I don't use it, every thing displays properly.

Here is my html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css" type="text/css" />
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="assets/js/html5shiv.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->

</head>

<body>

<div class="container"> 

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <div class="stacktwo"> <img src="assets/images/IMG_7079.JPG" width="200" height="200" alt=""/> </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">      
            <div class="stackthree"> <img src="assets/images/IMG_7079.JPG" width="200" height="200" alt=""/> </div> 
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">  
            <div class="stacktwo"> <img src="assets/images/IMG_7079.JPG" width="200" height="200" alt=""/> </div>
        </div>                      
    </div>  
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

css is same as above site.

Comment: posting your code would help...

Comment: I ran a JS fiddle with bootstrap.css and nothing seemed amiss. Can you specify the exact conflict and post some code?

Comment: the image loses it's border with bootstrap...

Comment: http://www.bootlint.com/

Comment: Post an actual example of your problem please.  Your question will not be able to help anyone else with the same problem if that page changes or goes away, so post your problem code here.

Comment: Use your browser's inspector?